# RewriteRule with string starting "http://"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems working out how I can do the following using htaccess:

`http://isitup.org/http://example.com` => `http://isitup.org/example.com`

I think the problem is the second double slashes, but I can't think of a solution.

Here's my current (failed) attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^http://([^/.]+\.[^/]+)/?$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.[^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.[^/]+)$ check.php?domain=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the original request line instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /http://([^/\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^http:/ /%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The reason for that is that Apache removes multiple slashes in the request URL.

Comment: Ah so that's what was happening. Thanks a ton, it works a treat.

Comment: @Sam: You could just use something like this to see what’s arriving at the server side: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ RewriteRule .+ /?$0 [R]`

Answer (score 1):

Well, that pattern you're repeating should be `([^/]+\.[^/.]+)`, but that's only going to be important when DNS names with more than two elements show up.

Your main problem is probably that the last redirect should be to `/check.php?domain=$1`.  Unless `mod_rewrite` is going to choke in general because that's not a valid W3C URL.  But we can hope.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, and I've corrected my errors. Unfortunatly the first rewrite still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the `RewriteRule` starts *after* the server information.  So, in the URL `http://www.server.com/path/to/file`, a `^` will begin matching at `/path/to/file`.

So if you are creating URL's as you described above, you'd actually need to match the first `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^/http://([^/]*)/(.*)$ /$1/htdocs/$2 [R, NE]
```

That should provide you the ability to map the following:
`http://isitup.org/http://example.com/path` => `http://isitup.org/example.com/htdocs/path`

If you are providing virtual hosting, you might just consider using an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html) or a name-based [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html) instead.

Comment: No; there's no leading slash on the URL portions `mod_rewrite` is matching against.

Comment: Hrm...  All the mod_rewrite examples in the Apache docs start with the prefix `/` - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

Comment: I thought `mod_rewrite` just acted on the request line, which would be `GET /http://example.com HTTP/1.1` in the OP's sample.

Comment: Thanks, but again this doesn't work. As a note, I don't actually need the paths it may come with, only "example.com".